# ocultar mostrar div con mouseover y mouseout

Tags: javascript

Pues lo dicho, estoy intentando que un div, definido en css como "hidden", aparezca cuando paso por encima el raton con "onmouseover" y que, al quitarlo, vuelva a ocultarse con "onmouseout". Pero no funciona, es como si no estuviese ese bloque. He probado a definirlo como visible de la etiqueta html y funciona perfectamente el "onmouseout", pero sigue sin funcionar "onmousever"

Como siempre, muchas gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>hola</div>
<div id="bloque" style="visibility: hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui hic 
    assumenda similique aut blanditiis est atque molestias, reiciendis
     facere minima obcaecati velit molestiae architecto rerum facilis libero 
     dolore magni quo!</div>
<script>
    function mostrar(){
        var trozo = document.getElementById("bloque");
        trozo.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function ocultar(){
        var trozo = document.getElementById("bloque");
        trozo.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    var trozo = document.getElementById("bloque");

    trozo.onmouseout = ocultar;
    trozo.onmouseover = mostrar;
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el div lo ocultas con hidden, el disparador mouserover no se activa nunca.

Una solución puede ser usar un div padre para activar o desactivar el div hijo.
Quedaría algo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>hola</div>
<div id="padre">
    <div id="bloque" style="visibility: hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui hic 
    assumenda similique aut blanditiis est atque molestias, reiciendis
     facere minima obcaecati velit molestiae architecto rerum facilis libero 
     dolore magni quo!</div>
</div>
<script>
    function mostrar(){
        var trozo = document.getElementById("bloque");
        trozo.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function ocultar(){
        var trozo = document.getElementById("bloque");
        trozo.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    var trozo = document.getElementById("padre");

    trozo.onmouseout = ocultar;
    trozo.onmouseover = mostrar;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ouuuu yeah,

Muchas gracias lfpp